# Как подключить fontawesome 5 локально с компьютера?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

я скачал fontawesome 5 на комп, не могу подключить, подскажите, кто знает...

Comment: Так же, как и нелокально — прописать в html-коде правильные пути к файлам fontawesome

Comment: Я подключаю в шапке сайта fontawesome.css а оно не работает

Comment: Мне это не подходит. Мне нужно подключить просто файл а потом через css добавить иконку

Comment: Я подключил css но он не работает

Comment: art.poletaev27@gmail.com

Comment: Дошло, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0):

Папку с `fontawesome 5` перенесите на один уровень с файлом стилей

`/css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css
/css/style.css`

в в самом файле стилей допишите в самом верху

`@import url('/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css');`

на последнем проекте подключал через

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Проверял как локально так и на сервере